# symfony twig form entity type checkbox column responsive

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have create a form with an entitytype with multiple choice. On my view i have all checkbox line by line. How can i make for exemple 3 checkbox on line if it's on tablet and 6 when it's on computer (using bootstrap col-) ?

Comment: This is more a css question than symfony.

Comment: I have seen we can override form fields template but don't know if it's possible to do what i want

Comment: you can render checkbox on your own, you don't have to override template.

Comment: I have add some additionnal information. My original field is an Entity field with expanded true and multiple true. I have add 2 pictures on an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you must rename your question to customizing form rendering in symfony.

so you can customize the form rendering by

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="someclass">
{{ form_widget(form.age) }}
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Also you can work with form theming, there is already bootstrap theme with symfony you need to add in config.yml so all forms will use bootstrap

```
twig:
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

or do it for every template by adding

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
```

refer to [How to Customize Form Rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

In fact i have not explain correctly .
Symfony display checkbox for entity field like this
[checkbox display normaly by symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrzKa.png)

And i want this
[checkbox in column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxZ7K.png)